# Can I listen for events, like a song ending, with the Spotify API?

Tags: javascript, spotify

Can I listen for events, like a song ending, with the Spotify API?

If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Add an observer for `models.EVENT.CHANGE` on the player object. When this fires, check that playing is `false`. The song has ended if the position of the player object is the length of the playing track, or if the playing track is `null`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by add an observer? This is a spotify specific event emitter?

Comment: See the docs for more information. The docs for the Application class contains a code sample: http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/preview/reference/2edfee4d46.html

Comment: Those docs say I should have a `models.application` property but my `models` object does not contain one.

Comment: I don't think trying to match the criteria you outlined works. My duration never reaches the max.