# Detect the end of a song using Spotipy

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm using [Spotipy](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/) and [LyricsGenius](https://github.com/johnwmillr/LyricsGenius) to open lyrics on a web browser from a terminal.

I can open a url for one song, but have to run the script each time to run consecutively. What are some ways to detect the end of a song using Spotipy?

```
import spotipy
import webbrowser
import lyricsgenius as lg

...

# Create our spotifyObject
spotifyObject = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

# Create out geniusObject
geniusObject = lg.Genius(access_token)

...

while True:

    currently_playing = spotifyObject.currently_playing()
    artist = currently_playing['item']['artists'][0]['name']
    title = currently_playing['item']['name']
    search_query = artist + " " + title

    # if (currently_playing has changed):
        song = geniusObject.search_songs(search_query)
        song_url = song['hits'][0]['result']['url']
        webbrowser.open(song_url)

    webbrowser.open(song_url)
```

I was reading relevant threads such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328890/can-i-listen-for-events-like-a-song-ending-with-the-spotify-api), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805871/detect-end-of-a-tracks-playback-with-spotify-web-api-playback-sdk), and read through documentation  but could not find an answer to my question if this could be handled by Spotipy. I would appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used time.sleep(length) with the argument 'length' standing for the remaining duration of a current track.